# Installing Plugins from Cloud p2 repository in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, plugins, p2

I have been recently reading a lot about p2 for a requirement of mine.
Most of the p2 documentation online points to p2 for RCP.

My requirement is for a plugin repo. I have a plugin that is used within
Eclipse IDE.

I dnt want to change the repo location but based on the Eclipse Version,
if the user looks for Install New Software or Check for Updates it needs
to download the respective plugins.

My repo currently contains all the plugins for all the versions. but i
need to everytime give a different URL to my user based on the Version.

For e.g i am using Eclipse 3.7(Indigo). I install the plugin thru
Install New Software by adding the p2 Repo URL. Now the user decides to
for some requirement move to Eclipse 3.6, I want him to connect to the
same p2 Repo URL and download the plugins created for Eclipse 3.6.

This is definitely possible using p2 Discovery, or i could categorize
the downloads using composite repository but i dnt want to do any of
these. Just want to kno is there any API that i can hold on to, so that
before processing the URL and finding the updates, i can check the
version of Eclipse and redirect it based on the version to an internal
URL. This is possible in RCP, want to kno if i can do it in Eclipse p2 UI.

All the p2 UI looks to be internal classes. Any directives would be
appreciated.

Malai

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you want to customize p2's UI. Actually you can restrict which features can be installed depnding on bundles' version.

If your plug-ins only works for Eclipse 3.6, you can define it to require '**org.eclipse.ui.workbench**' `[3.6.0,3.7.0)`, use version range [3.7.0,3.8.0) for Indigo. P2 will strictly follow those contract, only allow to install them into according Eclipse version.